# Angular cli source directory option not working

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am trying to create the new `angular-cli` project with `--source-dir` option but its creating directory as `true`.

Full command `ng new foobar --prefix foo --style scss --routing true --skip-git true --source-dir web --dry-run`

**Angular version**

[image]

**Output**

[image]

Comment: What happens when you put quotes around `web` and run the same command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this command instead:

`ng new foobar --prefix foo --style scss --routing true --skip-git true --source-dir=web --dry-run`

You just need to put an equal (`=`) between the `--source-dir` and `web`.

Output:

```
The option '--source-dir' is not registered with the new command. Run `ng new --help` for a list of supported options.
create foobar/e2e/app.e2e-spec.ts (288 bytes)
create foobar/e2e/app.po.ts (208 bytes)
create foobar/e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json (235 bytes)
create foobar/karma.conf.js (923 bytes)
create foobar/package.json (1317 bytes)
create foobar/protractor.conf.js (722 bytes)
create foobar/README.md (1022 bytes)
create foobar/tsconfig.json (363 bytes)
create foobar/tslint.json (3040 bytes)
create foobar/.angular-cli.json (1243 bytes)
create foobar/.editorconfig (245 bytes)
create foobar/web/assets/.gitkeep (0 bytes)
create foobar/web/environments/environment.prod.ts (51 bytes)
create foobar/web/environments/environment.ts (387 bytes)
create foobar/web/favicon.ico (5430 bytes)
create foobar/web/index.html (293 bytes)
create foobar/web/main.ts (370 bytes)
create foobar/web/polyfills.ts (2405 bytes)
create foobar/web/styles.scss (80 bytes)
create foobar/web/test.ts (642 bytes)
create foobar/web/tsconfig.app.json (211 bytes)
create foobar/web/tsconfig.spec.json (304 bytes)
create foobar/web/typings.d.ts (104 bytes)
create foobar/web/app/app-routing.module.ts (245 bytes)
create foobar/web/app/app.module.ts (395 bytes)
create foobar/web/app/app.component.html (1173 bytes)
create foobar/web/app/app.component.spec.ts (1103 bytes)
create foobar/web/app/app.component.ts (208 bytes)
create foobar/web/app/app.component.scss (0 bytes)
```

Based on the output of the command, the `--source-dir` option looks like it is deprecated. It will likely go away in the future. I am not seeing a replacement for it in the `--help`.

Comment: I did not found any reference about ```--source-dir``` in ```--help```.  Why only ```--source-dir``` required ```=``` for ```argument``` ?

Comment: You find more about the option [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/new). I do not know why this one only works with `=`. I have always used `=` with all the options, so I am a bit surprised it works without them. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
ng new SportsStore --skip-git --skip-tests --directory ClientApp
```

It would appear that the switch `--source-dir` was deprecated.

The previous command creates the following output:

```
CREATE ClientApp/angular.json (4195 bytes)
CREATE ClientApp/package.json (1286 bytes)
CREATE ClientApp/README.md (1028 bytes)
CREATE ClientApp/tsconfig.json (543 bytes)
CREATE ClientApp/tslint.json (1988 bytes)
CREATE ClientApp/.editorconfig (246 bytes)
CREATE ClientApp/.gitignore (631 bytes)
CREATE ClientApp/browserslist (429 bytes)
CREATE ClientApp/karma.conf.js (1023 bytes)
CREATE ClientApp/tsconfig.app.json (270 bytes)
CREATE ClientApp/tsconfig.spec.json (270 bytes)
CREATE ClientApp/src/favicon.ico (948 bytes)
CREATE ClientApp/src/index.html (297 bytes)
CREATE ClientApp/src/main.ts (372 bytes)
CREATE ClientApp/src/polyfills.ts (2838 bytes)
CREATE ClientApp/src/styles.css (80 bytes)
CREATE ClientApp/src/test.ts (642 bytes)
CREATE ClientApp/src/assets/.gitkeep (0 bytes)
CREATE ClientApp/src/environments/environment.prod.ts (51 bytes)
CREATE ClientApp/src/environments/environment.ts (662 bytes)
CREATE ClientApp/src/app/app.module.ts (314 bytes)
CREATE ClientApp/src/app/app.component.html (25467 bytes)
CREATE ClientApp/src/app/app.component.ts (215 bytes)
CREATE ClientApp/src/app/app.component.css (0 bytes)
CREATE ClientApp/e2e/protractor.conf.js (810 bytes)
CREATE ClientApp/e2e/tsconfig.json (214 bytes)
CREATE ClientApp/e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts (644 bytes)
CREATE ClientApp/e2e/src/app.po.ts (262 bytes)
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
```

These are the versions installed on my box:

```
$ node --version
v10.16.0

$ npm --version
6.9.0

Angular CLI: 8.3.0
```